# Accented characters in Sphinx headings

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils

I want to include accented characters in a Sphinx heading such that I will see the following result:

```
Finalé
```

I have tried the following strategies:
Use the unicode character directly such as:

```
Finalé
======
```

but the character is considered invalid by Docutils.

Also, I have tried using the `strip_html` specification in conf.py along with the following text:

```
Final&eacute;
==============
```

But the text is left unchanged and the HTML entity is passed through.

Can anyone suggest a way of handling accented characters in Sphinx that will work in all situations and where the final output may be HTML or Latex?

Comment: I cannot reproduce any problem. Having `Finalé` as a heading works fine. Do you get an error message? I also don't know what you mean by "`strip_html` specification".

Comment: Is your file saved in UTF-8 and are on Python3?

Comment: Deleting the character é´ and re-typing it fixed the problem so it must have been with the keyboard or editor.